# How to render FunctionComponent when passed as parameter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning React (and typescript) and trying to render a FunctionComponent received from a function parameter, but nothing is being displayed. Here's my code:

```
    const myComponent: FunctionComponent = () => <h3>Hello World</h3>;

    const renderComponents = (theComponent: FunctionComponent) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {theComponent}
            </div>
        );
    };

    return renderComponents(myComponent);
```

However, if I simply return the raw HTML code:

```
 return <h3>Hello World</h3>;
```

It works fine.

How do I render a FunctionComponent from a function parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theComponent` is the function itself. If you want its output you have to invoke it or JSX it:

```
const renderComponents = (theComponent: FunctionComponent) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {theComponent()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You’d need to capitalize it for jsx usage:

```
const renderComponents = (TheComponent: FunctionComponent) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TheComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Still a FunctionComponent is a JavaScript function, definitely you should run it to see it's result, in ReactJs there is a new syntax which its name is JSX, and it runs the FunctionComponent (JavaScript function) by other way:

```
const renderComponents = (theComponent: FunctionComponent) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <theComponent />
            </div>
        );
    };
```